# Why NSUserDefaults backup to iCloud but not syncing through all devices?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, icloud

I’m trying to have the NSUserDefaults to be synced through iPhone and iPad, but it is not!, It is backing up to iCloud for each device, but not syncing from one device to another.

Any idea why would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [UserDefault](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) documentation:

> With the exception of managed devices in educational institutions, a
>   user’s defaults are stored locally on a single device, and persisted
>   for backup and restore. To synchronize preferences and other data
>   across a user’s connected devices, use NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore
>   instead.